# Basis to Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let H be a separable hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$. How can we construct another orthonormal basis $\{f_k\}$ such that for any k, inner product of $f_k$ with infinitely many(all?) $e_i$ is non zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick some unit vector $v$ with nonzero coefficients, say $$v = 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} e_n$$ The operator $$Tx=x-2\langle x,v\rangle v$$ is unitary, because $T^2=I$ and $T=T^*$. (Geometrically, $T$ is the reflection in the hyperplane $\{v\}^\perp$.) Therefore, the vectors $f_n = Te_n$ form an orthonormal basis.  Also, 
$$\langle f_k, e_n\rangle = \delta_{kn} - 2 \langle e_k,v\rangle \langle e_n,v\rangle = 1-\frac{9}{2^{k+n}} $$ 
is never zero for the above choice of $v$.